# How can I make a six-pointed star design using 3 rectangular shapes?

Tags: html, css

I am making a design using CSS like this image. [image: question design image]

Here is a parent element having 3 child elements. How can I make All child elements are overlapping one another without using: `position: absolute;` in 3 children. How can I make same pattern using `position: static;`.

```css
.container {
  width: 370px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 185px) auto;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff, #fff, #eee, #ddd, #ccc);
}
.outer-flower {
  width: 80px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px auto;
  left: 155px;
}
.outer-flower:nth-child(1){
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.outer-flower:nth-child(2){
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.outer-flower:nth-child(3){
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="0"></div>
      <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="120"></div>
      <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="240"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for ways using only ```position: static``` ? to get the 3 rectangles to stay like that on the picture?

Comment: Any justification for requiring `position: static`?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to center all three `outer-flower` in the `container` using
`position: relative` on `.container` and apply following css on `outer-flower`

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

As they are in the center then you can rotate them accordingly:

- No need to rotate the first element
- Rotate the second element by `120deg`
- Rotate the third element by `240deg`

```css
body{
  height: 500px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 370px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 185px) auto;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff, #fff, #eee, #ddd, #ccc);
}

.outer-flower {
  width: 80px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.outer-flower:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.outer-flower:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(120deg);
}

.outer-flower:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(240deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="0"></div>
  <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="120"></div>
  <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="240"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use [data-rotate] attribute in CSS  or remove it from the HTML? Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

When you are not using absolute, every element will be either after one another or even in next lines based on the display property. If you have `display:inline-block` then you can have 3 divs in a single row. Then applying `position:relative` to the divs in order to move them to a single place and then rotating should be able to meet your requirement. The code is as follows:

P.S: I have changed the dimension values a little bit.

```
<style>

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.outer-flower {
  width: 78px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  height: 240px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.outer-flower:nth-child(1){
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  position: relative;
  left:80px;

}
.outer-flower:nth-child(2){
  transform: rotate(0deg);

}
.outer-flower:nth-child(3){
  transform: rotate(240deg);
  position: relative;
  right:80px;

}
</style>
```

Output:

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using absolute but to maintain the divs as position static we cannot position them using left and top - static just ignores them.

Instead we can use margin positioning and no CSS position property need be set on any of the elements.

This snippet needs a bit of refinement to get the alignment exactly right (don't forget to allow for the border widths if needed, though box-sizing helps) but is given here as a pointer to a way forward.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  width: 370px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 185px) auto;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff, #fff, #eee, #ddd, #ccc);
}
.outer-flower {
  width: 80px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer-flower:nth-child(1){
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.outer-flower:nth-child(2){
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  margin-top: -350px;
}
.outer-flower:nth-child(3){
  transform: rotate(240deg);
  margin-top: -350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="0"></div>
      <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="120"></div>
      <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="240"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid to avoid `position:absolute`

```css
.container {
  width: 370px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: grid;
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #fff, #fff, #eee, #ddd, #ccc);
}

.outer-flower {
  grid-area: 1/1; /* make all of them on the same track so they will overlap */
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.outer-flower:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(120deg) }
.outer-flower:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(240deg) }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="0"></div>
  <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="120"></div>
  <div class="outer-flower" data-rotate="240"></div>
</div>
```